# How to link Heroku to Godaddy domain ?

Tags: heroku, deployment, godaddy-api

I have followed all the stack overflow answers I found on the topic but none of them fixed my issue.

I have a Heroku app "lagora.herokuapp.com" which is running and I'm trying to connect it to www.logora.fr through Godaddy.
On the heroku interface, I've added the domain with the CLI heroku domains:add www.logora.fr.

[image: heroku page]

On the Godaddy interface, I've changed the CNAME (www to herokuapp) to redirect it from GoDaddy to Heroku. 
[image: GoDaddy page]

This setup displays nothing. I've been struggling and waiting for hours now. 
Do you have any ideas what's happening ?

Comment: you can follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWyaV_ZtLS0  works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest since Godaddy is not the best to manage your DNS is to get a Cloudflare account and change your nameservers in Godaddy (below the rules) to point to Cloudflare so that it handles your DNS. Here is a [link](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698-Configure-Cloudflare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS).

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, as it does not resolve the question between Godaddy and Heroku